# SharePoint with AngularJS and Angular

Tags: development, angularjs

I dont have access to the server side scripting or Farm administration.
I have access to only Client Side Scripting & technologies.

I have found AngularJS quite easy to integrate with the Client Side Scripting just using REST API.

How to use Angular for client side implementation without the using the Servers/Server side implementation.

All the reference implementation on Angular uses Node.js or HTTP Servers etc.
Is it possible to do Angular development only using the Browser, and are there any reference guides available?

Answer (score 2):

There is this course on Pluralsight: [Building SharePoint Apps as Single Page Apps with AngularJS](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-sharepoint-apps-spa-angularjs). The author shows how to build SPAs using AngularJS deployed using a SharePoint-hosted add-in (app).

You will need a subscription to Pluralsight to be able to access the course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **REST API** and **AngularJs** to achieve requirement. The code example from the link below for your reference.

[SharePoint REST API and AngularJs for 2013, 2016 and Online](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/AngularJs-for-SharePoint-2ace8405)

In SharePoint Online/2016/2019, I suggest you use **SharePoint Framework client-side web parts** to achieve your requirements.

Example code: [SharePoint Framework Client-Side Web Part Samples & Tutorial Materials](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts)